# Storing million records as XML from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I want to store the content of a SQL Server table which has million of records and 60 odd columns, into a flat file as XML. I tried using 'Select * from table-name for XML path, root' and stored the output through SSIS script task into a flat file. However, the process is writing only partial data into the flat file. The XML data is getting cut.
How to store the entire 1 million record into a flat file?
I have tried with top 10 records, still, it didn't help.

I cannot use the RECONFIGURE commands in SQL Server box since I don't have permission.

Comment: After how many characters is it truncated? What does the code in the script task look like?

Comment: The data is getting truncated after 2033 characters. The script I have used -
   SqlConnection rmccon = new SqlConnection("--The Connection String--");
            rmccon.Open();
            SqlCommand rmccmd = new SqlCommand();
            rmccmd.CommandText = "Select top 10 * from table-name for XML path, root";
            rmccmd.Connection = rmccon;
            string xml_file = (string)rmccmd.ExecuteScalar();
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\abc.txt", xml_file);